# How to show a background image resized into ImageButton size?

Tags: android, android-studio, imagebutton

I have a multi level LinearLayout to show 4x6 ImageButtons for an advent calendar. But when I want to set the background of the ImageButton, it is too big. How can I set the image background to fit the ImageButton size? I want to show 24 pieces of present boxes in a nice grid.

```
<ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/buttonOne"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="25"
            android:background="@drawable/present"
            android:fontFamily="@font/christmas"
            android:onClick="playOne"
            android:text="1"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/button_text_size" />
```

Comment: Have you tried adding height and width as pixels instead of wrap_content?

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you want to do can be done changing/adding 2 things:

1. Its an ImageButton, so dont use the `android:background` property, but the `android:src` with the same drawable
2. Then add the property `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` which basically adjusts the image to fit the view while maintaining aspect ratio

I think that should do the trick, else you can also try

3. Use the `android:scaleType` property, I would try using `fitXY` but here are all the possible scale types: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType

EDIT: Also, you might need to change your width and height properties, either specify a size in dp, use constraints, or wrap your ImageButtons in a [GridLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout)